# I'd like to compare data in two worksheets and copy a cell if there's a match

Tags: excel, vba, compare

I'd like to match column A between two worksheets, and if there is a match, data of column B (sheet1) of the corresponding row should be copied to column B (sheet2).

Sheet 1:

COLUMN A-----------------COLUMN B

Company name 1----------Startdate 1

Company name 2----------Startdate 2

Company name 3----------Startdate 3

etc.

Sheet 2:

COLUMN A

Company name 1

Company name 1

Company name 1

Company name 2

Company name 2

Etc.

I need to do this for multiple files which have varying number of rows.

The way I tried it is below, but it ends up only copying data to C3. Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

```
Sub Startdatum()

cntcomp = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Component").Range("A2", Worksheets("Component").Range("A2").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
cntbedrijf = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Bedrijf").Range("A2", Worksheets("Bedrijf").Range("A2").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count

For i = 2 To cntcomp

For j = 2 To cntbedrijf

    If ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Component").Cells(1, i).Value = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Bedrijf").Cells(1, j).Value Then

        ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Component").Cells(3, i).Value = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Bedrijf").Cells(2, j).Value

    End If

Next j

Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this (revised):

```
Function Startdatum(cell As Variant, cellrange As range, Optional celltarget As Variant) As String
For Each j In cellrange
    If j = cell Then Startdatum = IIf(IsMissing(celltarget), j, celltarget): Exit Function
Next
End Function
```

Put that into a new module, then you can enter into the first cell =Startdatum(A1,$C$1:$C$7,D1)

- A1 is the cell you want to compare.
- $C$1:$C$whatever (the $'s maintain the range when you drag it down) is the range of cells you want to compare it with...
- D1 is the cell you want to copy if there is a match

Drag down to do the whole range...

Comment: Well, this does compare the data, but it only copies the content of the  matching cell. 

I need to compare two names, if those match, i need to copy the date which is two columns to the right of the name. So, where it says 'Startdatum = j' in your formula, it actually needs to be 'Startdatum = j + 2 columns'

Comment: I've been trying, but I really don't know how to achieve the whole 'j + 2 columns' thing :p Any advice there? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Thanks for revising. Getting close! But I think it's easier to explain if I put up a little sample of the data. I'll edit the original post.

Comment: Right now, it copies a date, but it corresponds to the row of sheet 2, while it should correspond to the row of sheet 1 to which it matched.

Comment: Have you tried =Startdatum(A1,Sheet2!$A$1:$A$7,B1)? (into C1 on sheet 1)

Comment: I've tried that, doesn't work, unfortunately. What I need, is the 'celltarget' not to be the same row as the 'cell', but to be the same row as the matching 'cellrange'.

Comment: Oh well, did you have any luck?

Comment: Actually, yeah :P turns out my original code worked, just that i placed the order in 'Cells(1, i)' the wrong way around. It should have been 'Cells(i,1)'... (i felt kinda stupid ;)